# Advance next() to peek() with multipeek

Tags: rust

I'm using Rust Itertools MultiPeek.  How can I efficiently or conveniently advance the next() iterator to the current position of the peek() iterator?

```
fn main() {
    let v = "abcd";
    let mut mp = itertools::multipeek(v.char_indices());
    if let Some((byte_offset, c)) = mp.peek() {
        println!("peek: offset {}, char {}", byte_offset, c);
    }
    if let Some((byte_offset, c)) = mp.peek() {
        println!("peek: offset {}, char {}", byte_offset, c);
    }

    // Update next to current location of peek assuming
    // we'd rather not keep track the number of peeks

    if let Some((byte_offset, c)) = mp.next() {
        // would like to have Offset 2, char c
        println!("next: offset {}, char {}", byte_offset, c);
    }
}
```

Playground [link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=86876e51ca26d1e2406cc21707ae76df)

Comment: simply `mp.skip(2);` or `mp.nth(2)`

Comment: The minimal example is perhaps over simplified.  I'd rather not track how many characters were peeked and skip() and nth() cause O(n) walk pf the UTF-8 characters I've already peeked.

Comment: maybe do a better example so, also for exact sized iterator should be O(1)

Comment: Tried to clarify the example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps `MultiPeek` is not the solution to your problem at all.

It sounds like you are iterating through a string, and at some point, you need to look a little further forward. Depending on what you see, you then either keep going or wind back to where you were before you started 'peeking'.

Instead of using `MultiPeek`, you could just clone the iterator you are using at the point where you need to start looking forward. Then, when you have looked far enough ahead, you can either drop the clone and keep going forward with the original iterator, or drop the original iterator and use the clone. Something like this perhaps:

```
fn main() {
    let v = "abcd";
    let mut iter = v.char_indices();
    let iter_save = iter.clone();
    if let Some((byte_offset, c)) = iter.next() {
        println!("peek: offset {}, char {}", byte_offset, c);
    }
    if let Some((byte_offset, c)) = iter.next() {
        println!("peek: offset {}, char {}", byte_offset, c);
    }

    // Here we decide if we are going back to the 'save' point or continuing
    // on forward (for this example I assume we are rewinding)
    let mut iter = if true {
        iter_save
    } else {
        iter
    };

    if let Some((byte_offset, c)) = iter.next() {
        println!("next: offset {}, char {}", byte_offset, c);
    }
}
```

Most iterators are relatively cheap to clone - in the case of `CharIndices` it looks like it contains a `usize` and two pointers.

`MultiPeek` is much more expensive: it has to maintain a growable 'buffer' of the peeked items so that it can deliver them up later.