# What are the detriments of having an Iterator return itself?

Tags: rust, iterator, sequence, traits

Is a pattern that includes an iterator that returns itself an anti-pattern? Is this a good idea, or not?

```rust
impl Iterator for MySequence {
  type Item = Self;
```

My sequence returns an element, and it's not immediately apparent why that element can itself could not be a sequence? Is this good practice?

Comment: I believe the question is a bit too abstract to be answered, an example where this pattern would be useful would allow a more answerable question.

Comment: @FilipeRodrigues My iterator models a sequence, think like 'A' .. 'Z' should seq.next() return an element or should it return a new sequence that starts at that element?

Comment: An iterator conceptually yields values in a sequence, to me it sounds like what you're describing is an just a type that happens to have a method called `next` that mutates internal state, but is not an iterator. Using what you're describing with `collect` or any of the other iterator trait functions, for instance, might be a bit unergonomic. I guess an alternative question would be, what do you gain by making this an iterator?

Comment: For me `impl Iterator for MySequence` is itself problematic. You want a sequence to be _iterable_ (i.e. be able to return an iterator), but not _iterator_. I.e. it would be nice to create two independent iterators over the same sequence. Having said that, I think it's fine for iterator over a type to return values of that same type. For example, Python doesn't have a `char` type, so iterating over a string yields single-element strings. In Rust, `slice::windows()` operates on slice and produces slices.

Answer (score 2):

The only method that the `Iterator` has for you to implement is:

```rust
fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item>
```

If `Self::Item` is `Self` then there would be no way to get anything out of the iterator other than more iterators.

You could of course implement other methods and/or traits that would allow you to obtain values from the iterator. This is not the behaivour expected by many of the use cases for iterators in the standard library (or for that matter 3rd party libraries).

Some examples:

- Iterator methods such as [`sum`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.sum), [`cmp`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.cmp), [`min`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.min) etc expect to receive the values directly from `next`.

  You could work around this by implementing underlying traits like [`Sum`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Sum.html), [`Ord`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/cmp/trait.Ord.html), etc for your iterator
- Other methods like [`map`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.map) could be used, but they would be less ergonimic.
- Generic functions & structs may express requirements on type parameters in terms of the iterator's item. An example of this is the [`collect`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.collect) method, which collects the iterator's items into a container - but to do that it needs to know what type the items will have.

In short - because your iterator does not comply to the expected behaivour, you will be battling to use it many of the places where you would expect to use an Iterator.

What [is useful](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62256714/1411457) is an iterator that can be cloned, such that you can for instance return to a point in iteration if needed. You mentioned in the comments:

> You can also save any value of seq.next() which is itself an iterator.

If the iterator implements `Clone` then you can save it with:

```
let saved = iter.clone();
```

That has the advantage that you are only cloning it when needed, rather than on each iteration.

Comment: Sure there would. I mean for example I did it here... https://crates.io/crates/letter-sequence `assert_eq!( seq.to_string(), "A" );
seq.next();
assert_eq!( seq.to_string(), "B" );` You can also save any value of `seq.next()` which is itself an iterator.

Comment: That's not an `Iterator`, it's another way to model a sequence (more akin to a state machine).

Comment: @Jmb that's a fair point, I just didn't see it documented anywhere. It actually seems like an anti-pattern something rust should potentially even warn about, I was just wondering if `Item = Self;` on an iterator could ever be not-a-mistake. This question does state why it is a mistake, but it leaves the conclusion out. Is there ever a case where an iterator can return Self and it fulfill your definition of an iterator?